# When does the facebook login finish and return successful?(Android)

Tags: java, android, eclipse, facebook, authentication

I am working on implementing Facebook login to my Android application and just got finished with the login flow tutorial. However I am unsure of where to set up the change to a different activity after a successful login. I trid looking online but most of the help is from a year or two ago and is out of date. Any help will be appreciated. Also if you need to see some code let me know. I wasn't sure what would be needed for an example and I don't want to paste it all. Thanks in advance

Answer (score -1):

like this

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    uiHelper = new UiLifecycleHelper(this, callback);
    uiHelper.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ...
}

private void onFacebookSessionStateChange(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
        SessionState sessionState = state == null ? session.getState() : state;

        switch (sessionState) {
            case OPENED_TOKEN_UPDATED:
            case OPENED:
            case CREATED_TOKEN_LOADED:
                makeAnyFacebokRequest(session);
                break;

            case CLOSED_LOGIN_FAILED:
                ErrorLocalization.showToast(TAG, getApplicationContext(), exception);
                break;
        }
    }
```